# Remove extraneous divs from panels output

Tags: 8, panels

I have a Panels page I am constructing and there are some divs that are interfering with the content in the layout.

At the top of my panels region output, it has:

```
<div class="block-region-featured-news-top-left" data-region-name="featured_news_top_left">
```

How can I remove this? I do not see a base twig file for this.

Comment: I don't use Panels, but I'm wondering which template twig debug says is printing this markup. If you don't find the markup in this twig file, then the div is defined in code as `'#type' => 'container'` and you have to find it in the variables of the template preprocess hook.

Comment: Looks like it’s injected on prefix and suffix keys, and are required for IPE to function correctly. Going to request changes to the CSS grid style from our front end.

Comment: If you need the attributes, but don't want the div, can't you change it to a span?

Comment: Is there a way to alter or override the build method? I’m not sure what the preprocess hook name would be

Comment: I don't know Panels, thought from your last comment you've located the prefix and suffix keys already.

Comment: I did, but it is within the Panels class that builds the output, in the module.